# What geoid does WGS 72 use?

Tags: geoid

I see from the [WGS Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System):

> Currently, WGS 84 uses the EGM96 (Earth Gravitational Model 1996) geoid, revised in 2004.

I see there is an older EGM84 geoid but I couldn't find anything that states the WGS 72 standard uses it.

What geoid does WGS 72 use?

Comment: If I'm reading this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) correctly, the EGM84 geoid model has a resolution of 200 km. Because WGS72 and WGS84 (latitude-longitude-h) are much closer than that, you should be able to safely use the EGM84 geoid model or even the EGM2008 (10km resolution)

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, I saw the information about the different resolutions. I was more curious to know if the WGS 72 specification and/or standard was tied to a specific geoid as documented for WGS 84.